# How can I create a nested JSON file from a Pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like below:

```
 df.head(2)

Ord MOT  MVT  CUST  CreationSla  CreationPlanned CreationProposed  PickupSla  PickupPlanned PickupProposed
 12  TR    TT   DEA  12-3-2020      12-3-2020      12-3-2020       14-3-2020   14-3-2020    14-3-2020
 15  ZR    TD   DET  15-3-2020      15-3-2020      15-3-2020       16-3-2020   16-3-2020    16-3-2020
```

I want to create a nested JSON file in the below format:

#### Expected output

```
{
    "Ord" : "12",
    "MOT" : "TR",
    "MVT" : "TT",
    "CUST" : "DEA",
    "milestone" : {
        "creation" : {
            "sla" : "12-3-2020",
            "plan" : "12-3-2020",
            "proposed" : "12-3-2020"
        },
        "Pickup" : {
            "sla" : "14-3-2020",
            "plan" : "14-3-2020",
            "proposed" : "14-3-2020"
        }
    }
}
```

How can this be done in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to loop over rows of your dataframe.

Then with each row, you create a dictionary. The full idea is like this:

```
result = []
predefined_columns = ['Creation', 'Pickup', 'Departure']
mapping_cl = []
for column in df.columns:
    flag = False
    for sub_str in predefined_columns:
        if sub_str in column:
            flag = True
            mapping_cl.append(sub_str)
            break
    if not flag:
        mapping_cl.append(False)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    item = {}
    for cl in mapping_cl:
        if cl:
            item[cl] = {}
    for i, column in enumerate(df.columns):
        if mapping_cl[i]:
            cl_name = column.split(mapping_cl[i])[-1]
            item[mapping_cl[i]][cl_name] = row[column]
        else:
            item[column] = row[column]
    result.append(item)
```

Now `result` is a list of `dict` as you want:

[image]

Comment: what if I have subcolumn Deperature  with its timestamps mentioned .

Comment: So the point is you need to predefine all the columns name that you want to split it up. Then you will check the column if it appears in that list or not, if it does, you will split it up then. I will change my code to suitable to it

Comment: That would be nice

Comment: Hope that could help

Comment: I just edited, hope this one will solve your problem with as `predefined` columns as possible

Answer (score 4):

You can create a JSON template and send data to it:

```py
d = """{
    "Ord" : "%s",
    "MOT" : "%s",
    "MVT" : "%s",
    "CUST" : "%s",
    "milestone" : {
        "creation" : {
            "sla" : "%s",
            "plan" : "%s",
            "proposed" : "%s"
        },
        "Pickup" : {
            "sla" : "%s",
            "plan" : "%s",
            "proposed" : "%s"
        }
    }
}
"""
js = []

for item in df.values:
    js.append(json.loads(d%tuple(item.tolist())))

print(json.dumps(js))
```

## Output:

```
[{"Ord": "a", "MOT": "TR", "MVT": "TT", "CUST": "DEA", "milestone": {"creation": {"sla": "12-3-2020", "plan": "12-3-2020", "proposed": "12-3-2020"}, "Pickup": {"sla": "14-3-2020", "plan": "14-3-2020", "proposed": "14-3-2020"}}}, {"Ord": "b", "MOT": "ZR", "MVT": "TD", "CUST": "DET", "milestone": {"creation": {"sla": "15-3-2020", "plan": "15-3-2020", "proposed": "15-3-2020"}, "Pickup": {"sla": "16-3-2020", "plan": "16-3-2020", "proposed": "16-3-2020"}}}]
```

Comment: @Rahulrajan You can imort `json`, I changed my answer

Comment: a template with keyword arguments [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-examples) and passing a dict to it will be more robust than this

Answer (score 4):

Since you mentioned Pandas, I use `wide_to_long`, and then `groupby` to create your format. Notice this requires you to change the `level` when your data format changes.

```
s=pd.wide_to_long(df,stubnames=['Creation','Pickup'],i=['Ord', 'MOT', 'MVT', 'CUST'],j='type' , suffix='\w+').stack().unstack(level=-2)
js=[{**dict(zip(s.index.names[:-1],x)),**{'milestone' : y.reset_index(level=[0,1,2,3],drop=True).to_dict('i') }} for x , y in s.groupby(level=[0,1,2,3])]
js
[{'Ord': 12, 'MOT': 'TR', 'MVT': 'TT', 'CUST': 'DEA',
 'milestone':
  {'Creation':
  {'Planned': '12-3-2020', 'Proposed': '12-3-2020', 'Sla': '12-3-2020'}, 'Pickup': {'Planned': '14-3-2020', 'Proposed': '14-3-2020', 'Sla': '14-3-2020'}}},
 {'Ord': 15, 'MOT': 'ZR', 'MVT': 'TD', 'CUST': 'DET',
  'milestone':
  {'Creation':
  {'Planned': '15-3-2020', 'Proposed': '15-3-2020', 'Sla': '15-3-2020'}, 'Pickup': {'Planned': '16-3-2020', 'Proposed': '16-3-2020', 'Sla': '16-3-2020'}}}]
```